# Reopen "How to deal with a coworker who hates your religion"

Tags: discussion, status-completed, specific-question, reopen-request

I would like the SE community to vote on reopening this question: [How to deal with a coworker who makes hateful comments about my religion?](https://workplace.stackexchange.com/questions/58504/how-to-deal-with-a-coworker-who-makes-hateful-comments-about-my-religion)

I felt this original reason for being put on hold was the focus on the comments made on social media which is indeed off - topic for The Workplace. My edit a few minutes ago re-focused the question on the work-place and the OP's desired outcome: To have the offensive behavior immediately cease. I also addressed why the OP would like to speak up: Because he finds the behavior offensive, unprofessional and wholly unbecoming of a coworker in a professional workplace.

I am not able to add an additional answer due to the question being on hold.

Comment: Aside: the question is now reopened.

Answer (score 4):

(Voted to re-open)

I am an Indian, and have faced this problem of hatred towards my faith.  Having been there, I would like to add an answer. (Discussed with @Enderland on chat, but seems like the answers there are from a non-Indian point of view.)